# Powershell pipe modified registry value

Tags: powershell

(How) can I pipe this (without using the variables)?

```
$regPath="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize";
$regProp="AppsUseLightTheme";

$toggledDarkMode = (Get-ItemProperty $regPath $regProp).$regProp -bxor 1
Set-ItemProperty $regPath $regProp $toggledDarkMode;
```

Something like:

```
Get-ItemProperty ... | Set-ItemProperty -value ($_ -bxor 1) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ForEach-Object` to wrap the call to `Set-ItemProperty`:

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name $regProp |ForEach-Object {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name $regProp -Value ($_ -bxor 1)
}
```